# Ubuntu Installer won't start on an Asus ROG STRIX X470-F

Tags: system-installation

I tried to boot my machine, an Asus ROG STRIX X470-F, but the Ubuntu Disc never showed anything, all I saw was the pointer blinking for over 10 min, but nothing showed, I tried with 18.04 and 19.04, but got the same with both, any idea what can be the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: I should have said Cursor, not Pointer.

Comment: The reason is Nvidia graphics. Use `nomodeset`to boot the live session and also the installed system, until you install the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: I don't have nVidia Graphics, but an AMD Radeon.

Comment: So, only the CPU integrated graphics? Make sure you're booting in UEFI mode and you need to adjust other UEFI settings. Also, how did you made the USB?

Comment: No, I do have an AMD Radeon Card in it, I have the BIOS configured to use both EFI and Legacy, I tried with both, USB and DVD, same thing on both.

Comment: I think the problem here is that Ubuntu or any other Linux distro doesn't have the driver for the SATA device in the motherboard, because after a while of waiting it says it cannot find "storage" devices.

Comment: That can be an issue as well. Change mode to AHCI.